# labels on lattice plots

Tags: r, label, lattice

I want to add labels to lattice plot. I conditioned the plots on "Users", the plot looks ok; however, the ID label are repeated in both the conditioned plots.

I want only the labels (which is ID of a subject i.e. x-axis on this plot) with the datapoints. I don't know why the same label appear on both the plots below.

Any suggestions please.

```
xyplot(Cmax ~ ID | USER, data=THC4,layout=c(1,2),scales=
list(x=list(relation="same"),y=list(relation="same")),
panel=function(x, y, ...) {
panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
panel.text(x=THC4$ID,y=THC4$Cmax,labels=THC4$ID, pos=3)})
```

Here's the the [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woGzU.jpg):

[image: img]

Comment: Just leave image links, someone would edit for you.

Comment: I have added the image link...please provide your suggestions on the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `THC4$` in  `panel.text(x=THC4$ID,y=THC4$Cmax,labels=THC4$ID,pos=3)` you are getting the full set of labels in each plot. Try

```
panel.text(x=x,y=y,labels=x, pos=3)})
```

for your last line.